# Relationship between union of cartesian products and cartesian product of unions two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It's given

For sets $A, B, C$ and $D$, let 
$$L::= (A \cup B) \times(C \cup D)$$ $$R::= (A \times C) \cup (B \times D).$$ Prove that $R \subseteq L$.

**Attempted solution**: $$\forall(x, y): (x, y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times D) \Rightarrow (x,y)\in (A \times C) \vee(x,y) \in (B \times D) \Rightarrow$$ $$[x\in A \wedge y \in C ] \vee [x\in B \wedge y \in D ] \Rightarrow$$  $$x \in (A \cup B) \wedge y \in (C \cup D) \wedge (x\in B \vee y \in C) \wedge (x\in A \vee y \in D) \Rightarrow$$ $$\bullet (x,y) \in ((A\cup B) \times (C \cup D)) \wedge (x\in B \vee y \in C) \wedge (x\in A \vee y \in D) \Rightarrow $$ $$(x,y) \in (A\cup B) \times (C \cup D) \iff(x,y) \in L$$ $$\blacksquare$$
Is there a problem with the last line of the proof, if yes, where? I have doubt on the last implication. Thanks

Comment: The last line is fine, because from A & B you can infer A. You're only proving a one-way implication so you're free to discard the other conjuncts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
&(x,y)\in(A \times C) \cup (B \times D)\\  
&\implies (x,y)\in(A \times C) \vee (x,y)\in   (B \times D)\\
&\implies (x\in A \wedge y \in C) \vee (x\in B \wedge y\in D)\\
&\implies (x\in A \vee x\in B) \wedge (y\in C \vee y \in D)\\
&\implies (x\in(A \cup B) \wedge (y\in C\cup D))\\
&\implies (x,y)\in (A \cup B) \times (C \cup D)
\end{align}$