# Error in a bogus proof showing equivalence of Cartesian Product and Union of sets of pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fake-proofs

This question is related to another [answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061741/relationship-between-union-of-cartesian-products-and-cartesian-product-of-unions), but I am struggling to relate the two (as a self-learner, I have no other avenues to get some feedback).

The problem which I am trying is the one shown in the below screenshot. The red marked lines are where I think there could be a problem.

[image]

- On the first red mark, I am wondering whether distributivity of OR
  over AND is missing something.
- If there is no problem in that line (the linked answer for the related problem had assumed that line to be correct), then the error is in the last line. I suppose the reasoning $x \in (A \cup B) \space and \space y \in (C \cup D) \iff (x,y) \in L $ cannot be taken to conclude that the two sets $L$ and $R$ are equal.
- But if my above reasoning is correct, how to fix the proof to show that $R \subseteq L$ ? Would a simple statement that $ (x,y) \in L \implies R \subseteq L$ enough?

Comment: It seems that the fix would be a change from an iff to an if, which would make $(x, y) \in R$ imply $(x, y) \in L$ but not necessarily vice versa

Comment: good idea, but also, is the distributivity of OR over AND complete and correct?

Comment: The set on the line with the red question mark will always contain the set in the line above it, but not the other way around. For example, what happens if $x \in B$ and $y \in C$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $C \cap D = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$x \in A$ or $x \in B$ and $y \in C$ or $y \in D$

you cannot reach the conclusion

$(x \in A$ and $y \in C)$ or else $(x \in B$ and $y \in D)$

so

$(x \in A$ and $y \in C)$ or else $(x \in B$ and $y \in D) \implies$ $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ and $y \in C$ or $y \in D$

but not the other way around, which explains both why the proof is bogus (the statements are not an joined by an iff) and why $R \subseteq L$

Comment: i think i get it, if it is an implication rather than biconditional